# NSString get 100 characters from start

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How to get a substring from NSSTring from index 0 to 99. i.e. first 100 characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[myString substringToIndex:100]
```

You need to be sure that index 100 is valid, i.e. length of string is at least 100. Otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
[str substringToIndex: 100]
```

Comment: Note that the index has to be checked.